# Find the value of $\tan w$

Tags: trigonometry

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/NlAPf.jpg)

This is a question in my school's exercise book
I couldn't think of any equation to be formed to solve it
Please teach me

Comment: Draw the triangle out and do the geometry.

Answer (score 2):

First, the diagram makes it clear that $w^\circ = \theta$.

Identically, it is true that $\tan\theta = \dfrac{\sin\theta}{\cos\theta}$. From the Pythagorean theorem, we know that $\cos^2\theta = 1 - \sin^2\theta$.

$$\begin{align}
\tan w^\circ &= \tan\theta \\
&= \frac{\sin\theta}{\cos\theta} \\
&= \frac{\sin\theta}{\sqrt{1 - \sin^2\theta}} \\
&= \frac{k}{\sqrt{1 - k^2}}
\end{align}$$

However, notice that $w^\circ$ is in quadrant III, where $\tan$ is negative. Since we did some work with squaring and principle roots, we need to correct our signs:

$$\bbox[yellow,5px]{\tan w^\circ = -\frac{k}{\sqrt{1 - k^2}}}$$

You should find this [list of trigonometric identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities) *very* useful in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Remember,

$$\sin^2\theta + \cos^2\theta \equiv 1$$

For all $\theta$. Given this, and that $\sin\theta = k$, how can we find $\cos\theta$ in terms of $k$? How can we then find $\tan\theta$? Can you think of where to go from there seeing that $w = 360 - \theta$?